# Exposed select return type

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I am new to ktor and Exposed.
I want to write a function that returns `Category` object by `id`

here is my data class

```
@Serializable
data class Category(
val id: Long,
val name: String,
val count: Int
)
```

here is my `main` function

```
fun main() {
embeddedServer(
    factory = CIO,
    port = 8080,
    host = "0.0.0.0",
    module = {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
        configureDependencyInjection()
        configureCategoryRouting()
        configureImageRouting()
        Database.connect(
            url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres",
            driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
            user = "postgres",
            password = "74279744fz"
        )
```

and here is my function that should return a `Category`

```
fun getCategoryById(id: Long): Category {
    val category = transaction {
        Categories.select {
            Categories.id eq id
        }
    }
    return category
}
```

but the returned `category` is not a `Category` but its a `Query` class.

how can I convert it to `Category`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to map values from `ResultRow` into your `Category` data class.
Like:

```kotlin
Categories.select {
   Categories.id eq id
}.map { row ->
  Category(row[Categories.id], row[Categories.name], row[Categories.count])
}
```

Please also check the [wiki](https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/wiki/DSL#read).